# I need to make my Page load faster, way faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, load

I am a very amateurish web designer. Very very.... I got this friend of mine that asked me to do a real estate page for him and well, I did it. Fact is, I used so many .js and css that the page is actually loading extremely slow, at least in the beginning. It looks as if there is nothing going on while it loads so I need to do at least one of these things:

Full page Progress bar - Show the user the stuff is loading so he doesn't think the page won't load at all.

Make loading way faster - I tried minifying, I tried compressing images, I tried scripts to load unnecssary js only when they are needed...still looks like crap and loads like crap.

I know it's not well done...but I'm learning and trying. Please help because I got a deadline going on. I repeat. I know it is far from good, that's why I'm here. I appreciate any feedback and help.

site is: http://www.apt-inlisbon.com

Edit: Damn..I had forgot about the images size...can't believe it....thanks. I will try that as soon as I get home. Lesson learned. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is really too broad _and_ won't ever help anyone else. You need to hire a consultant or ask a friend for help. SO not being a forum or chat. Personally I would have a conversation with your client about expectations because it sounds like you cannot live up to your promises.

Comment: As a quick and dirty way to reduce the load time, remove the massive images you are using. There's no point in loading in full size images to use them as thumbnails.

Comment: For me your page is not loading at all. Your included files like .css, .js, bootstrap etc. are all giving me a 404.

Comment: Ouch on the downvotes guys. It's not too vague. The solution was easy to find. Come on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS and CSS are not your problem.

Your images are absolutely gigantic. Most of them, even the thumbnail sized ones, are 3600px wide. Resize them down to the max size you're going to need and save them for web with Photoshop or Gimp or some image editing app.

If you want to further optimise your images, you can run them through other apps like JPEG-Mini.

Also, check your site for 404 errors in the Chrome web-inspector, and fix them.

Good luck with your deadline and be careful of setting your client's expectations too high.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that and respond later...

Comment: Aye, the solution was to optimize the images. I did it easily using kraken.io and jpegmini. Kraken.io rocks by the way!

Comment: You deserved an upvote for sticking with the folks that helped you figure it out. As for "too broad", I reckon there are some folks who want things on a gold platter.

Answer (score 3):

Your site is waiting for all images to load, but you have tons of very big images. It took me 2min to download all the images (163 MB). If you have to load this mouch images, load them dynamically with javascript.

[image: Site]

Comment: Seriously. I will do that...I'm still using the first images for test....god damn...I am absolutely flabbergasted by my own ignorance. You guys rock